# Object doesn't support this property or method error in IE7 jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-7

IE7 is showing this error message: (no other browser is showing any error except ie7)

```
Message: Object doesn't support this property or method
Line: 97
Char: 2
```

And line 97 has this:

```
$('.megamenu').megaMenuCompleteSet({
```

The complete javascript code is this:

```js
<script> 
$(document).ready(function($){
    $('.megamenu').megaMenuCompleteSet({
        menu_speed_show : 300, // Time (in milliseconds) to show a drop down
        menu_speed_hide : 200, // Time (in milliseconds) to hide a drop down
        menu_speed_delay : 200, // Time (in milliseconds) before showing a drop down
        menu_effect : 'hover_slide', // Drop down effect, choose between 'hover_fade', 'hover_slide', etc.
        menu_click_outside : 1, // Clicks outside the drop down close it (1 = true, 0 = false)
        menu_show_onload : 0 // Drop down to show on page load (type the number of the drop down, 0 for none)
    });
});
</script>
```

Can somebody advice me what is wrong with line 97?

Thanks!

---

**UPDATE SOLVED:**

i was using the latest one, i fixed it myself, it was all my fault, i had the jquery lib loaded two times with different versions, it was not making any trouble on other browsers except IE7. But after debugging i found the multiple lib loading and removed and there were no errors :)

Thank you everyone!

Comment: Try `alert(jQuery().megaMenuCompleteSet);` to see if the plugin has been loaded.

Comment: Thank you @brandon-boone
Error was multiple lib loading :(

Answer (score 1):

What version of the MegaMenu script are you using? I can see this in their changelog:

```
06/23/2012 – Version 2.11
Fixed an issue occurring under IE7 in megamenu.js
```

Comment: Thank you @sergiu 
I was using the latest build of megamenu.js
Error was multiple lib loading :(

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is the issue but you don't need to pass JQuery as an argument since it is global so:

```
$(document).ready(function($){
```

should be:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
```

This may be the issue since your JQuery plugin appears to be what is not working properly.

Comment: You're right, this isn't necessary, but it's certainly not invalid. See ["Aliasing the jQuery Namespace" in this article](http://api.jquery.com/ready/). You would more normally see this as `jQuery(document).ready(function($) {});`. This construct is primarily used to prevent collisions with other libraries using the `$`.

Comment: Thank you @BrandonBoone and marteljn
I tried this one too, but the errors stayed the same.
It was the jq lib loaded multiple times issue. But surprisingly it was only showing error in IE7, not even in IE8. 
Anyways, thank you everybody for your time and help :)